# In C++, what is the use of template parameter when it doesn't appear in the following class or function declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Many times I see these types of codes.
What is the use of template in the code below?
I ask this because the template parameter `T` does not appear in the declaration.

```
template <typename T>
struct op_pointer_to_mat;
template <typename T>
struct op_pointer_to_col_vect;
```

Does it mean that the definition of `op_poineter_to_mat` and `op_pointer_to_col_vect` is somewhere else with template parameter `T`?

Comment: The definition of a template class is the same the template parameter is only used in the body of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a **forward declaration**. The class must be declared fully somewhere later. Could be the same file or a different header. It just lets the compiler know that the name `Test` is valid and the blanks will be filled in later.

```
template<typename Type>
class Test;

template<typename Type>
class Test
{
public:
    Type valueFor() { }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! (didn't know what this is called, so I couldn't find it on the web.. :) )